# ServiceBus Topics: Subscription Filter Rules not working when sending a message via Logic App Connector

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an **Azure Logic App** that sends a message to a Topic using the **Azure Service Bus Connector**. I even use the Properties field and the values are indeed propagated together with the message. 
But for some reason filtering doesn't work on these properties, though the filter works when sending a message with another tool (like Service Bus Explorer).

SB Connector, that sets Properties:

[image]

Message send to Topic in SB and visible in Subscription without Filter. (Rule 1=1)
[image]

But this message is never available in a Subscription with Filter.
[image]

Though messages sent with other "Publishers" (e.g. Test with SB Explorer) do appear in this subscription if they match the filter criteria.
[image]

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess right now (and I'll verify this later today) is that the current Service Bus Connector is casting all properties as "strings" and not detecting when it is an Int32, so the rule isn't successfully working.  Can you try either modifying your rule to detect the string "1" or modifying the property to send a string and see if that works?  If so we should be able to add the work to deal with integers better when in properties.  Let me know

EDIT: After looking into it, this appears to be the case.  If you can verify treating it as a string works I'll know for sure where we have the gap and can work on prioritizing the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, it is casted to a string. Unfortunately that can't be seen in SB Explorer. I even had that guess before and tried to change the filter. Unfortunately I used double quotation marks; but single quotation marks are required. So the filter expression >>>  BigData='1'  <<< works. Would appreciate, if this will be fixed, so that the SB Connector can deal with other types as well.

Comment: Great to hear. Yes I'll file the bug for this and in future will fix. Let me know if it's blocking any major implementations so I can help engineers prioritize